# While replacing special characters few characters are not getting replaced using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a sentence and I'm trying to ignore the special characters and space ( only for static portion though) while comparing with another customer msg. Here dynamic portion would be {#val#} place. I have to maintain the space there. Other portion of customermsg can have space or without space. So the code is below.

Im trying to compare both but ignoring special characters,

```js
var sentence = "special characters ignore ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )  _ - + = { [ } ]  \\  \"  ? / End {#val#} {#val#}";
var customermsg = "special characters ignore ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )  _ - + = { [ } ]  \\  \"  ? / End 987 7889";

sentence = sentence.replace(/(^|.)\s($|.)/g, (x, g1, g2) => (x == "} {" ? x : g1 + "\\s?" + g2));
var separators_regex = /{#val#}|([\\s?])|([!-\/:-@[-`{-~])/gi;
sentence = sentence.replace(separators_regex, (x, y, z) => y ? y : z ? "" : ".{0,5}");

console.log(sentence);
```

but the output of sentence is ,

```
special\s?characters\s?ignore\s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s?\ \s? \s?? \s?End\s?.{0,5} .{0,5}
```

but what I want is,

```
special\s?characters\s?ignore\s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s?End\s?.{0,5} .{0,5}
```

? and / is not getting replaced. Even if I try to do it like below,

```
var separators_regex = /{#val#}|([\\s?])|[?]|([!-\/:-@[-`{-~])/gi;
sentence = sentence.replace(separators_regex, (x,y,z,m) => y ? y : z ? "" : m :"" ".{0,5}");
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: I get `special\s?characters\s?ignore\s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s?\ \s? \s?? \s?End\s?987\s?7889`

Comment: Now I get `special\s?characters\s?ignore\s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s? \s?\ \s? \s?? \s?End\s?.{0,5} .{0,5}` This is in Chrome, not node.js, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, there is an additional "?" and i want to replace it. please help

Comment: Why am I getting so many more `\s?` than you are?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I have missed out few /s? while pasting. But What I want itto remove that one extra ?. Kindly help

Comment: Are you talking about the first `?` in `?\s?`? I don't get that.

Comment: How do you miss something when pasting? The computer does it automatically and shouldn't drop anything. Mistakes like that only happen if you copy it by hand instead of pasting.

Comment: @Barmer edited the content. Im talking about this "\s??" which needs to be "\s?"

Comment: I think that's happening because there are two spaces before `?` in `sentence`. The spaces get turned into `\s?` and then the literal `?` is kept.

Comment: @Barmar I want that  extra literal ? to be replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `[\\s?]` in `separators_regexp`. That leaves all `\`, `s`, and `?` in `sentence` unchanged. I think what you wanted to leave was the literal sequence `\\s?`, since that's what was added by the first regexp. So use `\\s\?` to match this sequence.

```js
var sentence = "special characters ignore ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )  _ - + = { [ } ]  \\  \"  ? / End {#val#} {#val#}";
var customermsg = "special characters ignore ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )  _ - + = { [ } ]  \\  \"  ? / End 987 7889";

sentence = sentence.replace(/(^|.)\s($|.)/g, (x, g1, g2) => (x == "} {" ? x : g1 + "\\s?" + g2));
var separators_regex = /{#val#}|(\\s\?)|([!-\/:-@[-`{-~])/gi;
sentence = sentence.replace(separators_regex, (x, y, z) => y ? y : z ? "" : ".{0,5}");

console.log(sentence);
```